# Suspend Time Based on Holidays Node Red

Tags: function, timer, node-red, suspend

I'm trying to suspend the eztimer node by an input of the holiday (Feiertage) - Node.
The Holiday node sends every day at 00:01 a boolean value if today is a holiday or not.
It's possible to suspend the timer by putting a message.suspend true or false.
So I've already tried a function with transform the msg.payload to msg.payload.suspend but it was not working. Then I tried to use the change function to set msg.payload.suspend from msg.payload - but it's also not working. I always get from the time the input is not supported.

tested function node:

```
var test = msg.payload;
msg.payload.suspend = test;
return msg;
```

[image: change node]

[image: Flow how it should look like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the "Move" verb in the change node not the "Set" (Festlegen) verb.

And the function node should be:

```
msg.payload = {
    suspended: true
}
return msg
```

In the old version you are trying to set the `suspend` field on what is probably a number (assuming you are using an inject node to trigger it). You can't do this, so you need to replace it with an object.

Comment: ok i've tried it like this:
(input -> "Feiertage" -> function -> timer)
input is a string using "isTodayHoliday" to trigger the Feiertage node for a boolean answer.
Function i've set up like you mentioned, then i also get the error "invalid object (msg.payload) input."

Comment: Look at the doc for eztimer again, the message should be in in `msg.payload.suspended` not `msg.payload.suspend`